Pairwise categorical comparison gt-summary table?
I am making a gt summary table. The table is split by "Category" and has 4 different columns. I want to add p-values, but only compare Category1 and Category2. Is this possible? I also want to make it as easy as possible, as I am new to R.
tbl_summary(
  dataexample, 
  
  include = c(var1, var2),
  
  by = Category
  
)%>%
  
add_p(
  list(
  all_categorical() ~ "fisher.test"
  )
) 


Do you still want to show all Categories, 1,2,3,4? Maybe just subset the data dataexample[ dataexample$myCategoryColumn %in% c("category1", "category2"), ]. Please provide example data.

Yes I still want to see all columns. The variables are categorical, answer is either 0/1.

Just subset (filter) the data frame before calling tbl_summary():
trial %>%
  select(grade, death) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = death) %>%
  add_p(list( all_categorical() ~ "fisher.test"))


filter(trial, grade %in% c("I","III")) |>
  droplevels() |>
  select(grade, death) |>
  tbl_summary(
    by = death) |>
  add_p(list( all_categorical() ~ "fisher.test"))



library(gtsummary)

